# Concurrent Solr DIH full-imports

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, dih

Our site is using Solr for search and filtering. We employ the DataImportHandler (DIH) to build our index and maintain it up to date. Using cron, we run one full clean import everyday (during slow hours) and incremental updates every 5 mins using the technique described here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport

Certain actions on our web application trigger updates to the index for specific documents. These updates are also handled via the DIH by adding additional SQL conditions to match the documents that need to be updated.

We're running into the issue that while one index update is running (full import takes ~10mins and incrementals ~30sec) any other requests to the DIH are ignored and so sometimes our application triggered updates are not being executed.

We're considering adding another architecture layer for job queues and workers and having all index update requests flow through the queue.

Has anyone run into this issue before and can suggest their specific solutions to this problem? Much appreciated!